# In Ghostscript how can I make a pause in output to the screen

Tags: ghostscript, display, pause

Under Linux, I am writing a Ghostscript program to read a fairly long (1320 lines) data file of longitude and latitude co-ordinates (a file installed with Gnuplot) eventually to draw a map. I have written various test files and the latest is to read the data and display each line using show and `showpage` In order to check that the lines read match the input file. I would like to pause the program's execution after each `showpage` until a key is pressed. Please, how can I do this?

This is my test program for keyboard input. I expect it may need significant changes:

```
%!
% Testing Keyboard input
%
% Depictions of the stack have top on the right
%
/Courier findfont 16 scalefont setfont

% string needs a size and leaves the created string on the stack.
/s 15 string def % longer string stores /00 in extra places in outfile ..
/lcount 0 def    
/vpos 750 def /nl 0 def
/newline {72 vpos moveto /vpos vpos 12 sub def} def

/inputfile (/dev/tty) (r) file def
%/inputfile (/home/Harry/Mercator/world.dat) (r) file def

/getdataline dataline into s ++> true, or false at end of file
{ /lcount 1 lcount add def
  inputfile s readline % was readstring
} def

{ 0 1 14 { s exch 0 put }for % clears string s to nulls
  getdataline 
  {newline s show}  % got a line
  {exit}  % end of file
  ifelse
  showpage
% ******* I want to pause here *******
} loop

inputfile closefile
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed the answer right before my nose, hidden in the terminal window behind my editor window. After each `showpage` in the preogram execution the message `>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<` appears in the terminal window, just what I wanted.